# In the game of Stratego, is it possible to destroy all 40 enemy units?

Tags: stratego

Stratego. Both opponents have 40 units each at the start of the game. My question is, is it real to destroy/kill/capture all forty enemy units during a single game? By "destroy" I mean also passive or mutual destruction, not necessarily an active kill. For example, if the opponent's spy is attacking our general, it is still counted as we have killed him.

Comment: The spy attacking your general will result in the general being killed, not your general. The spy always wins when attacking, and always loses when defending...

Comment: @mmathis No, the Spy only wins when attacking the Marshal (and the Flag). He loses against anything else.

Comment: @Dennis_E huh, guess I was playing wrong for decades!

Comment: @Dennis_E Is it possible that an old version of the game did have mmathis's version of the rule? I can't find an official source, but I also played that way decades ago and here's an unofficial source which uses that rule: https://howdoyouplayit.com/391/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [**official rules**](https://isfstratego.kleier.net/docs/rulreg/isfgamerules.pdf) of the International Stratego Federation, it is **impossible** to capture all 40 pieces of your opponent:

> **12 The end of the match**
>
> 12.1 A game ends when:
>
> - one of the flags is captured.
> - at least one of the players has no movable piece anymore. A movable piece is a piece that still has at least one legal move.

So if your opponent has a flag and one moveable piece, there are two possibilities.

1. it's your move: capturing either one of those pieces will win you the game.
2. it's his move: losing his last moveable piece also wins you the game.

In either case, the position is won for you with at least one opponent piece standing.

Comment: @anonymous downvoter: please indicate how I can improve this answer.

Comment: Wasn't me, but: "The ISF Game Rules are based on the Jumbo 
Stratego Original Game Rules".. Might be the wrong kind of official rules.

Comment: The Travel Rules i.e. lists under the original rules section "You also win, if your opponent can't move anything" which would be the case one round later http://www.nordicgames.is/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Stratego_Travel_Rules_EN.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot, TemplateRex. I've played a zillion of Stratego games and yes, it seems like it's really impossible to capture all forty enemy units. 39 is the maximum. Thus your newest answer is totally correct.

Comment: Is the concept of having "any movable pieces" meaningful for a player who isn't on move?  If all but one of Red's pieces is blocked in by bombs, and Red's last movable piece dies while attacking one of Blue's pieces, but Blue's next move would attack Red's bomb, would Red lose as soon as the last immediately-movable piece is destroyed, or would the game continue because one of Red's pieces would have become movable before Red's next turn?

Comment: In a several versions of the game (at least the 1990 video game) the game ends when a player cannot move, and not when a player has no movable pieces. So when the opponent loses their last piece, one still has one move to capture the flag.

Answer (score 16):

As Dennis_E mentioned, it is possible, but I would say it is improbable.

To destroy all enemy units, you would have to avoid the flag until the 40th capture. Additionally, one of the enemy's non-stationary pieces must be the 39th piece to be captured, and it must suicide itself on one of your pieces.  Otherwise, the game would have ended beforehand as the opponent would have been unable to move any piece during their turn, thus losing before you could destroy all 40 pieces.

What makes this improbable is that without assistance from your opponent, you would have to identify all the non-flag stationary pieces and destroy them before destroying the flag while ensuring the opponent maintains an additional non-stationary piece, which they must voluntarily throw at a piece that would destroy it on a turn preceding one where you are able to capture the flag.

I really cannot see a human opponent not forfeiting at this point unless they were colluding with you.

Comment: sorry, but this answer is incorrect under the official game rules, see my answer below.

Comment: @TemplateRex how so? The 39th capture is done by the opponent, on their last turn

Comment: Technically, TemplateRex is correct. The game is over when your opponent suicides his last movable piece. In some computer games, you can still capture the Flag because the programmer just didn't know. I do it all the time just for fun. Everything else in this answer is still correct, though.

Comment: @Dennis_E: Does the game end if a player has no immediately-movable pieces at the *end* of their turn, or only if the player still has no movable pieces at the start of their *next* turn?  Obviously if a Red's 39th piece suicides, no move by Blue could cause Red to have a valid move on Red's next turn, but I don't think the game should be considered over until a player in on move with no movable pieces.

Comment: @supercat At the end of their turn. If both players have no more moveable pieces, the game is a draw. The player whose turn it is doesn't lose.

Comment: @Dennis_E: I'm not talking about a mutual stalemate situation, but rather a situation where Red's last immediately-movable piece suicides on its turn, but Blue then captures a Red bomb, thus granting mobility to a Red piece behind the bomb.  I wouldn't think the fact that none of Red's pieces were mobile between the end of Red's turn and the end of Blue's turn should matter.

Comment: @supercat I know you weren't talking about a stalemate situation, but I presented it as an example. The 2nd player doesn't lose because he can't move. Instead, the game is a draw because neither has moveable pieces. In your example, Red would lose immediately when he suicides his piece.

Comment: It isn't probable, but it is neither unrealistic. One might imagine an endgame with very few pieces left. And the opponent has one piece left to gamble for your flag, and ends up on a bomb, just one turn before you capture the flag.

Answer (score 3):

I question the "improbable" about this. We've had lots of games where all the miners were eliminated, leaving it to the blood kill. (Yes, we know the importance of keeping a miner for the end--dummy flags are dangerous weapons.) If the weaker side has no scouts left this goes down fairly rapidly. If he does, we've seen drawn games due to the minimum number of pieces required to catch a scout (seven on the open board).

Comment: I always wondered how to catch a single scout in Stratego. Your answer contains much appreciated information.

Comment: It is improbable if you want to eliminate all pieces, not just the moving pieces.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe: I considered that a higher-order typo as in the rules as I recalled them you lost immediately on losing your last moving piece and therefore loss of all pieces is not possible.

Comment: You lose if you have to move and you have no movable pieces left. So it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Possible? Of course.
Realistic? That depends on your opponent's level.
Computers for example are really bad at Stratego. Against a computer, you can win almost every time by capturing all pieces. Against a decent human player, you should focus on capturing the flag ASAP.
But if you are so far ahead that you are in a position to utterly destroy your opponent, your opponent can just concede the game before you get the chance, especially when playing in a tournament setting.
I don't think it happens very often.

Comment: Computers can now beat humans at go and limit poker. I don't think a human stands any chance against a real AI in Stratego

Comment: @Andrey I would think so, but it seems no one has made a smart enough Stratego A.I. yet. The best one is probably Probe and that one is easily beaten. Also, Go and chess are open games; there is no hidden information. And Poker is a game of statistics.